# osmdroid put map in disabled state

Tags: android, osmdroid

How to put an **`osmdroid mapView`** in a disabled state, so it does not responds to touch, panning, zooming, ecc.?

I've tried with `myMapInstance.setEnabled(false);` but does not works.

Comment: I've resolved by modifying osmdroid source code to take account of this.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

`mMapView.setClickable(false);`